# Post Stream in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, uwp, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello lovely people of Stack Overflow.
Since yesterday I have a problem and I have been browsing SO since then.
I have a UWP Client and ASP.NET Core Web Api. I just want to send a stream to my web api but indeed this occurred to be harder task than i thought.

I have a class which I have only one property. The `Stream` property as you can see below:

```
public class UploadData
{
    public Stream InputData { get; set; }
}
```

Then Here is my code from my Web Api:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public string Post(UploadData data)
{
    return "test";
}
```

I have tried to read the stream From body but the result is same.
I can hit the post method `UploadData` is not null but my `InputData` is always `null`.

Here is my UWP's code for post request.

```
private async void PostStreamButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var dummyBuffer = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("this is dummy stream");
        var dummyStream = new MemoryStream(dummyBuffer).AsRandomAccessStream().AsStream();

        var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var inputData = new StreamContent(dummyStream);
        inputData.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        requestContent.Add(inputData, "inputData");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("url", inputData).Result;
    }
}
```

I have tried various of content types which none of them seems to work and I have no idea why. I would really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On client side send the stream content not the whole model.

```
private async void PostStreamButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var dummyBuffer = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("this is dummy stream");
        var dummyStream = new MemoryStream(dummyBuffer).AsRandomAccessStream().AsStream();

        var inputData = new StreamContent(dummyStream);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("url", inputData);
    }
}
```

NOTE: Do not mix `.Result` blocking calls with async calls. Those tend to cause deadlocks.

On server update action

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post() {
    var stream = Request.Body;
    return Ok("test");
}
```

Comment: Hello, I dont have Content property on my Request. I only have body.

Comment: @HasanHasanov, You are correct. My code was for previous version. Body is what you should be looking for.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this work behind the scenes. When you get a StreamContent (or any streamable thing) as an input/output of a service call, does the request/response just stay open until you dispose the stream object?  Trying to visualize how this works behind the scenes.

Comment: @JeremyArmstrong take a look at the [StreamContent](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamContent.cs) class for client side. pay attention to `SerializeToStreamAsync` method

Comment: On the server side it keeps the stream open till it is done with the request. if it closes it before the request/response is complete, not all the data will be sent.

Comment: When it keeps the stream open, I assume it is keeping the request/response open in order to keep transferring data, correct?  I assume it does this vs open a different connection to the server/client for the stream.