# Cannot get file from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send a file via a get request but this code is not working. I am using .NET Core and testing the API with Postman.

```
// POST api/values
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string filename)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream($"Scans/{filename}.obj", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

When I test the request through postman, I get this instead of my stream:

```
{
"version": {
"major": 1,
"minor": 1,
"build": -1,
"revision": -1,
"majorRevision": -1,
"minorRevision": -1
},
"content": {
"headers": [
  {
    "key": "Content-Type",
    "value": [
      "application/octet-stream"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Content-Length",
    "value": [
      "8785871"
    ]
  }
]
},
"statusCode": 200,
"reasonPhrase": "OK",
"headers": [],
"requestMessage": null,
"isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Comment: how about this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271947/post-stream-in-asp-net-core-web-api) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage` is from the previous version of the framework. You have to use a `IActionResult` implemented class.

You can return a file stream result via the controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(string filename) {
    var path = $"Scans/{filename}.obj";
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var response = File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); // FileStreamResult
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it's really odd that my code did not work but here is some working code. It appears HTTPResponseMessage is not capable of sending a file. rather, you have to return a FileResult object instead.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult Get(string filename)
    {

        string path = $"Scans/{filename}.obj";

        FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "application/octet-stream")
        {
            FileDownloadName = path
        };
        return result;


    }
```