# How to allow large upload in .net 6 web api

Tags: c#, .net, api

when allowing large uploads you can specify this in web.config in a mvc web application

```
httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx"
```

How do I do the same in appsettings.json

NOTE, this question is regarding .Net Core Web API using a program.cs and not MVC controllers.

Comment: Closing as its all in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming - takr @LeiYang's advice with the section **StreamingController.UploadPhysical**

Comment: I have edit the original question and clarified the question since this is not regarding mvc project

Comment: maybe helps: [Post Stream in ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42271947/1518100)

Comment: Sorry it does not